# How can I make a bed canopy?

Tags: modeling, rendering, materials

How can I make a bed canopy?

Both the modeling and the material?

Looking for something like these **[01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4RDs.jpg), [02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK8Md.jpg)**.

**UPDATE:**

So this is what I ended up with thanks to Nicola Sap suggestion and I'm pretty satisified with it. Thank you.

What do you think?

What about the material? (Now I'm just using mix of diffuse and transparent).

(credit to pixabay/Viscious-Speed for the floral background).

[image]

Comment: Great! I'm happy that you could make the most of my comment. I'll make it an answer then, for now without adding anything to it. The material looks pretty good to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer just to point you to the direction of **cloth simulations**.

1. Start with a **large circle** in the position of the highest point of the canopy, with a **"triangle fan"** face fill.
2. Remove one vertex along the circumference, to make an opening
3. **Subdivide** many times, minimum 6 but possibly 11-12.
4. Assign the central vertex to a **vertex group**.
5. Set up a **Cloth simulation and enable pinning** on the newly created vertex group.
6. Make the **canopy holder ring** using a simple torus mesh and enable collision.
7. **Enable collision on the bed** (or on a cube representing the bed's proportions, if your bed isn't ready yet).
8. **Bake** a cloth simulation
9. Choose a frame that looks right, and **"Apply"** the Cloth modifier.

Answer (score 0):

Cloth sim is the way to go. Here is a good tutorial:[Modeling with Cloth Simulation in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssYemC0j6Ag&t=1002s) I am sure you can adapt his techniques to this.

Comment: This is a [link-only answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) can you add more details that teach the reader how to use cloth simulation?

Comment: Scott, in this case I think that "link only" *is* an appropriate response in this case.  The OP's question is vague and actually would require "a very large answer."  (Much too large, I think, to try to detail here.)  Whereas, web-pages like the one Stan suggested are a very good place to begin to get that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a *42-minute* video, and it takes every bit of it.

I would further add to this comment that there really will be *two* aspects to getting a satisfactory result:  cloth simulation, and then texturing.  The cloth material will be very gauzy *(is that a word?)* and translucent.

I'd also add that, given that Blender 2.8 removes the original "Blender internal" renderer, replacing it with Cycles and EEVEE, the OP will need to learn about the *node-based materials* which drive the Cycles render engine.  For a glimpse of what I'm talking about, see *e.g.:*

https://www.blenderguru.com/articles/cycles-shader-encyclopedia

https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/create-realistic-materials-with-cycles

https://blenderartists.org/t/yet-another-thread-about-cycles-materials/562346

So, there are two challenges ahead of the OP:  first, to get a cloth material to lie correctly, then to make it look like it does in the reference photograph.